# How to ensure the firebase admin sdk is running?

Tags: node.js, firebase

I am new in firebase, I am trying to build the admin interface which allows admin to manage the data from firebase, such as delete auth user, change user password and so on. But I am not sure how to integrate?

```
console.log("hello");

var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./fir-auth-1f9cf-firebase-adminsdk-kguye-e386f4cfc6.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://fir-auth-1f9cf-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com"
});


// Initialize the default app
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var app = admin.initializeApp();

// As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("restricted_access/secret_document");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});

admin
  .auth()
  .getUser(uid)
  .then((userRecord) => {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log(`Successfully fetched user data: ${userRecord.toJSON()}`);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
  });
```

[image: error found when running the code]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a typo, have you tried changing this line:

```
var app = admin.initializeApp();
```

to:

```
var app = admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://fir-auth-1f9cf-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com"
});
```

?